# Date picker Start date one day or tomorrow

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I have an AngularJS site that opens in 1/1/2019

I have a datepicker than I wants dont allow pick date before this day, I achive with this

```
<div class="input-group date date-picker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date-start-date="01/01/2018" >
```

But I want after this day, the start date was 'tomorrow'.

To do this I use this

```
<div class="input-group date date-picker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date-start-date="+1d" >
```

But I don't know how to combine it and/or is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
$scope.tomorrow =tomorrow ;

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
            autoclose:true,
            startDate: tomorrow ,

        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sravya, but the problem is the 'tomorrow' date is not binding by angularjs... I try this

data-date-start-date="{{ tomorrow }}"

and define it in the js

tomorrow = "01/01/2018";

But don't works :-(

Comment: Edited just now...please check whether this solution works or not